# AWS - Cognito Identity with nodejs - What to do with tokens

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

So I'm trying to use Cognito Identity in my nodejs API. My goal in using Cognity Identity is to be able to give users a secure way to create a user account and log in. I'd like to use my API to make aws cognito calls to verify users by identifying them with their email address. My API will then give users access based on who they are, which is based on their email.

I was able to create a user, verify the user's email, and log in to get an AccessToken, IDToken, and RefreshToken. That's great, but at this point I'm not entirely sure what to do with these tokens. I'd imagine I can somehow use them to verify a user every time they make a call to my API, but I'm uncertain how to do that.

I'm imagining authentication flow going something like this:

User logs in with their password -> My API makes a call to aws to get tokens -> My API passes those tokens back to the user's mobile device -> Their mobile device stores these tokens -> AccessToken is used to verify all API calls until it expires -> RefreshToken is used to get a new set of tokens if AccessToken expires -> If RefreshToken is expired user must log in with username/password again.

Is that incorrect or an improper way of doing this? If I have the right idea, then how do I use the tokens to accomplish this? I wasn't able to find any documentation on the authentication process once a user gets their tokens. The only thing I can find that seems it might be able to accomplish this is here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html#initiateAuth-property

Comment: Have you seen this? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-tokens-with-identity-providers.html

Comment: @JeffBailey I have seen that. I was hoping for some code samples though :). Their description give me an idea of how it should work but no practical means of applying that knowledge.

Comment: Have you seen the samples? They cover things like refreshing and using access token (I believe) and there's a blog post about using the id token for APIGW.

Answer (score 0):

Your next step depends on what service you use and how you use it.

For example, for an API-driven application with Lambda / API Gateway, you'd [use Amazon Cognito User Pools](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-integrate-with-cognito.html) for your API resource methods and send the ID token as an `Authorization` header with your API call. (Yes, the name is misleading. It should be *Authentication* since the authorization logic is actually implemented in your Lambda function)

Then, your Lambda function can access the identity claim properties from the user pool using the `context` object (when you enable **Lambda proxy integration**) as:

```
const email = context.authorizer.claims.email;
```

or

```
const cognitoGroups = context.authorizer.claims['cognito:groups'];
```

If you haven't enabled **Lambda proxy integration**, you should make sure to pass those values in your body-mapping template.

You can find code examples [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonCognitoYourUserPoolsDemo) and [here](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/CognitoYourUserPools-Sample/Objective-C).

Comment: My API will not be using any other AWS service at the moment. That's something I'll likely be doing down the road, but right now I only want to use AWS Cognito to authorize and identify users. Once I can verify a user, my API will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good reference github application that demonstrates various aspects of cognito and how integrates with lambda, API Gateway, DynamoDB and other AWS services.

Here's a link:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-serverless-auth-reference-app